# In Nodejs , why cant I req object under GET method?

Tags: node.js

In nodejs using express 4.x, I receive an error `req.query is undefined`.
I have a layout.ejs file with a link `href="/editprofile?email=<%=user.email%>"` to prepare to direct to index.js with the GET method.
But I can not get the req.query object; it displays **undefined**. Please help, and thanks.

[layout.ejs]

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/">首頁</a></li>

                <%if ( typeof(user) != 'undefined' && user != null) {  %>
                    <li><a href="/logout">登出</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/editprofile?email=<%=user.email%>" ><img  src="/images/user.jpg"   height="25" width="25">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <% } else { %>
                    <li><a href="/login">登入</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/reg">註冊</a></li>
                <%} %>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

[index.js]

```
router.get('/editprofile',function(res, req, next){

    console.log("req.query.email:"+req.query);
    User.get(email,function(err,user){
        if(!user){
            req.flash('error','無此使用者!');
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        if(err){
                req.flash('error', err);
                return res.redirect('/');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: In your router.get(...) the function params res and req should be switched